Find and display a name from a list of names in 2 separate columns in Excel?

In the example image above I have a list of football teams and who they are playing, and I would like to display only 1 football team but in both columns
For example Everton is present in both column O and column Q. I would like to display only the rows where Everton appears, but in either of the columns. So the displayed teams would be Everton v Chelsea row 168, Manchester City v Everton row 170, and Everton v Nottingham Forest row 182, etc.
Is this at all possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

Do you mean you want to filter based on whether either column has "Everton" in it?

yes that is correct

The simplest would probably be with a helper column.
In a new (or empty) column (for example R2) you add this formula:
=OR(O2="Everton",Q2="Everton")

And then filter by this formula, if it says TRUE that means that Everton is present in one of the two columns.
